# RPi Sense Hat joystick runs loop only once

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am very new to python and coding in general and trying to get a few things to work on the Raspberry Pi3 and Sense Hat, please excuse any misuse of terminology. I am trying to use the joystick to call a script that displays a 15 second timer on the Sense Hat's LED matrix whenever it is pressed. So far I have been able to get the script to run once when the joystick is pressed, however I can not get it to run the script again if the joystick is pressed a second time. Is there anyway to make this possible?

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
from time import sleep
sense = SenseHat()


e = (0, 0, 0)
w = (255, 255, 255)

G = [0, 255, 0]
R = [255, 0, 0]
X = [0, 0, 0]

s = 15

timer = []

def time():
    for i in range(64):
        if i < s:
            timer.append(G)
        else:
            timer.append(X)


sense.set_pixels(timer)

for i in range(0, s):
    sleep(1)
    timer[i] = R
    sense.set_pixels(timer)

for i in range(0, 10):
    sense.clear()
    sleep(0.1)
    sense.set_pixels(timer)
    sleep(0.1)
    sense.clear()




while True:
    for event in sense.stick.get_events():
        if event.action == "pressed":
            if event.direction == "up":
                time()
                sense.clear()
```

Comment: I've never used the libraries here, but do you need to call `sense.set_pixels(timer)` again in the infinite loop at the bottom?

Comment: And maybe clear pixels by doing `pixels = []`?

Comment: No, because like I said, I've never used this library before. I can infer how it's used based on what you have here though, and it seems you need to call `set_pixels` to update the screen.